# Where to put a local xsd file in Jboss 4.05

Tags: java, xml, jboss, xsd

I am working on Jboss 4.05 , I have an xsd file that was on jboss.com and want to have it locally on my system, I can not find the right location to put this file, when starting the jboss I get this error:

Offending resource: class path resource [spring/my-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 75 in XML document from class path resource [spring/my-ranking-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'seam:instance'.

the problem started when jboss.com went down, i located the relevant xsd and downloaded it. i have tried putting it in the bin directory of jboss and also on the lib directory under the server to no avail.

thanks in advance,
Dov

Comment: I guess the real question is where does the xml parser takes the local XSD from (xerces in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the xsd needs to be in the class path.

It's the server that needs it then make sure the path to the file is in the Jboss start up classpath.  You can change the startup classpath in the *run.bat* or *run.sh* file.

If the probem is with a deployment then the file needs to go in that deployment's classpath.

ex: for my axis deployment the xsd would be in the classes directoy.

*jboss-4.0.2\server\default\deploy\axis.war\WEB-INF\classes*